# Consensus algorithm selection

Tags: staking, consensus, aura

We are looking to build private blockchain on Substrate. It should be scalable up to 300 validators. Like start with 3 and scale it to 300 later on. Does standard AURA suitable for this? Can AURA handle 300 validators without any problems? Or should we integrate Staking pallet instead?

Comment: When scaling to that number of validators with AURA, make sure to include a "punishment" mechanism to deal with (remove) inactive validators otherwise block production could be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AURA determines the next block author from a **given set of validators**. The [staking pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/staking) is used to manage **funds at stake by network maintainers**.

They can be used in correlation; AURA determines the next block author from a **given set of validators**, this set can be chosen based on the amount of **funds at stake by network maintainers**.

But to answer your question, I don't see a reason why you **can't** use AURA for a set of 300 validators.